# Import doesn't fetch records containing underscore character

Tags: mysql, import

I am trying to import data into MySQL using a CSV file. I have made sure I am using UTF-8 encoding while creating the CSV file.
One of the fileds (defined as varchar) has the following value:
http://chanclinics.com/about-us/meet-the-doctors/kate-thomas--dc.html?_ga=1.62264366.389087859.1488436781

MySQL skips this entire row and imports other rows. How do I make sure this row is imported? Seems like its an issue with underscore character.

My table:

```
select * from PHANI_MARKETING CREATE TABLE `phani_marketing` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `COMPANY_NAME` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDRESS_LINE1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDRESS_LINE2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ZIP_CODE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CITY` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REGION` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PHONE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTACT` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WEBSITE` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FACEBOOK` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TWITTER` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GOOGLEPLUS` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INSTAGRAM` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LINKEDIN` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YOUTUBE` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1798 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

This row is not being imported:

```
0   Melody Libatique    7200 S 180th St Back and Neck Pain Centers  98188   Tukwila WA  (425) 970-4655          "http://chanclinics.com/about-us/meet-the-doctors/kate-thomas--dc.html?_ga=1.62264366.389087859.1488436781"
```

This Row is successfully imported:

```
0   Middendorf Chiropractic 2021 SE Sedgwick Rd Ste 101 98366   Port Orchard    WA  (360) 871-5200      dataprotection@vortala.com  http://portorchardchiropractor.com
```

I use Table Data import Wizard on MySQL and provide CSV file as input.

Comment: Import how? Load Data infile or something else. Can you add a few rows from your file as text to the question together with your table definition please.

Comment: please provide CSV record file and MySQL script

Comment: i have used a PERL program to decode the text before inserting to the table.